# Nested JSON Object with array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want JSON object as follows in that personal, address and itm have sequence of json object.

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "state": "12",
  "personal": [          
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "contact":"1111111"
      "address": [     
        {
          "line1": "abc",
          "city": "abc",
          "itm": [  
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_detatils": {
                "itemname": "bag",
                "rate": 1000,
                "discount": 0,

              }
            }
          ],
          "status": "Y"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

}
```

But I am getting result as follows in that I want json array at address and itm_details.

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "state": "12",
  "personal": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "contact": "1111111",
      "address": {
        "line1": "abc",
        "city": "abc",
        "itm": {
          "inum": "1",
          "itm_detatils": {
            "itemname": "bag",
            "rate": 1000,
            "discount": 0
          }
        },
        "status": "Y"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**My PHP Code is as follow:**
In that I am creating simple array and after that array inside array but during encoding to json it's not showing sequence of json object.

```
$a=array();
$a["id"]="1";
$a["state"]="12";
$a["personal"]=array();
$a["personal"][]=array(
"name"=>"abc",
"contact"=>"1111111",
"address"=>array(
"line1"=>"abc",
"city"=>"abc",
"itm"=>array(
    "inum"=>"1",
    "itm_detatils"=>array(
        "itemname"=>"bag",
        "rate"=>1000,
        "discount"=>0,
        ),

    ),
"status"=>"Y",
    ),
    );

echo json_encode($a);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add one more array

```
//...
"address" => array(
    array(
        "line1"=>"abc",
        "city"=>"abc",
        // ...
    ),
)
```